# PHP - How I can extract 7z extension

Tags: php, zip, unzip, 7zip, php-ziparchive

I am wondering if PHP can extract the *.7z extension. I have searched a lot about it and I all what I see is *.zip, *.rar etc... but not 7z. Here is the code that I have tried. `ZipArchive();` is not supporting 7z.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x = $zip->open($target_path);

if($x === true) {
  $zip->extractTo('../uploads/ext');
  $zip->close();

  echo "Your zip file has been unpacked.";
}
else
{
  echo 'not unpacked!';
}
```

I have many 7z files and I am looking to let PHP unpack them to get information from them. I have looked at 7zip website for some resources but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

I'm using windows server 2012.

I hope that I explained it right.
Thank you.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: @Dr.Strange $x is returning false

Comment: your `$target_path` path was write and add `,ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` after `path`

Comment: @Dr.Strange Now it is returning  `TRUE` but when I go to `../uploads/ext` I cannot find it.

Comment: add `/` after `ext` like `../uploads/ext/`

Comment: @Dr.Strange Without having `,ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` `$x` returning `TRUE` for *.zip and I can see the files unpacked.  And its returning `FALSE` for *.7z. But when I have `,ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` *.zip and *.7z returning `TRUE` but no files found. I have tried `../uploads/ext/` still not working

Comment: Any update here? :)